# Does tire need immediate replacement?

Tags: tire, safety

I have received a hand-down bike from a friend that had a punctured inner tube which I have since patched, however during my fix I noticed that the tyre is not in the best condition when looking at the sidewall, and would like to know if the tyre is dire need of a replacement.

Thanks in advance for any response!

[image: current state of the tyre]

Comment: It looks like a nice rim - some nice tyres will make the bike look awesome.  Aside - check the brake pads too, they may be old and hardened as well.

Comment: Check the nipples around the spoke-holes for rust or damage from corrosion. While the tyre is off check the state of the rim-tape. If it's the same age age the tyre it probably needs replacing as well. A good insurance against impending punctures. Best would be to replace tyres, tubes, rim-tape and brake-pads as suggested by @Criggie.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you do need to replace the tyre. It can burst any time. You just leave the bike somewhere, hear a loud bang and that's it. If you are lucky. If you are unlucky, it happens when you are riding it and you crash because the bike is no longer controllable.

Comment: yeah I kinda thought that's the logical thing to do, thanks again for your answer!

Comment: @strox I just want to add that with more relaxed bike, or with larger tyre, such a hardened/worn tyre is less of an issue, with low pressure the tyre can still hold it together decently (almost safely), but with road tyres you start to have 4 or more bars of pressure, it is a lot of force acting on the tyre casing.

Answer (score 8):

If that was my rear tire, but I still had to ride a few miles to get home, I'd ride it as long as it lasts. I'm talking about easy, slow, flat miles on a paved road. Not screaming mountain descents or anything challenging.

If that was my front tire, I would walk home.

Either way, it goes in the trash as soon as I get home.

Comment: Good point about getting home.  I've dumped tyres in better condition than that.    This does look like gradual degradation, so its been brewing for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Yes replace that tire (if not both) immediately. This is called dry rot. Dry rot is caused by sunlight exposure, and ozone.